# Are there any disadvantgaes of using a part of the datagram in UDP to receive packets sequentially?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, udp, packet

The UDP protocol does not guarantee packets being received sequentially, but you could just use part of the datagram for a sequence number.

Compared to the guarantee of TCP, is the above solution for UDP equivalent?

Basically, I've been reading everywhere that UDP does not provide sequential receiving, but this seems like such an obvious fix that I was wondering if it is truly an adequate fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 'disadvantage' is that you lose a few bytes of data space.

However, by itself, it isn't a solution. You have to add ACK messages into your protocol so that the sender knows what you have and haven't received; you have to buffer sent datagrams at the sender until they are ACK'd in case you have to retransmit then; and you have to either buffer out of sequence datagrams or throw them away so you can reconstruct the sequence correctly. Having come this far, it would also be sensible for the sender to implement some form of flow control or pacing if it notices a lot of retransmission being required.

This is a good way towards implementing TCP. Most people give up at this point and use TCP.

Comment: UDP could offer advantages over TCP if messages are used to to report the present state of something, and the recipient is not interested in anything other than the present state.  Suppose Bob sends "Door is closed" or "door is open" messages when a door opens or closes, and will retransmit the door state periodically unless it receives a suitable "I heard door is closed" or "I heard door is open".  If shortly after Bob sends out "Door is closed", the door opens, Bob would send "Door is open" and not care about hearing an acknowledgment of the earlier "door is closed" message.

Comment: The problem is that if the "Door is closed" and "door is open" messages get swapped, the "door is closed" message may be the last one Bob hears.  Joe might successfully send a "I heard door is open" in response to the "open" message, but have his "I heard door is closed" message get dropped.  In that scenario, Joe would think the door was closed, but Bob would think that Joe thought it was open.  Oops.  Adding sequence numbers would avoid that.  Joe wouldn't have to process any packets that are received out of sequence--just make sure he doesn't process them.

Answer (score 1):

Using UDP in that fashion makes the application need to handle packet reconstruction and sequencing.  That creates overhead in the application layer of the network.  TCP is probably more efficient at handling that in the transport layer.

As well, UDP does not provide a mechanism for resending lost packets.  When your application notices that the sequence numbers skipped one, there is some ambiguity in the meaning.  Is there a lost packet or a delay packet?  Your application would need to be able to detect that, and be able to request that the packet be sent again via a packet number reference.

In other words, there is a reason for the overhead of TCP when in-order guaranteed delivery is required.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a form of partial reliability, inbetween TCP and UDP.

An option is to use SCTP-over-UDP ([SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), portable userspace & kernel [source](https://code.google.com/p/sctp-refimpl/)).  SCTP lets you set in-order for unreliable UDP-like streams , and also for partially-reliable streams (limited time or number of re-transmits)
.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could implement the missing features from TCP in UDP but that would destroy the purpose of UDP. The point is that the TCP implementation in your network stack peforms all the neccessary operations for you. (Involving packet reassembling and packet loss).

If you need TCP than you should use it. UDP is designed for packets where you don't care if they got lost (like VOIP, Gameserver, etc.).